# How to Set capability for IE browser to run in Headless mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to run the scripts in Headless mode for all the 3 browsers Chrome, Firefox & IE

The following is the code for Chrome:

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drive/chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    options.addArguments("headless");

    options.addArguments("window-size=1400,600");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

Note : Its working fine

Firefox:

```
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();

    firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./drive/geckodriver.exe");

    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();

    firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);

     driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

Note : Its working fine

IE:

Similarly i want to execute in IE with options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE does not have support for a headless mode (since IE nowadays does not recieve any kind of update or improvements.).

But you can use [trifle.js](http://triflejs.org/), a kind of browser that can emulate some IE versions in a headless mode, since its coded as a port of PhantomJS.

Comment: I couldn't find any example about trifle.js. How can I add trifle.js to my c# code

Comment: @UglukFromIsengard triffle runs using phantonJs api. So you need to download its .exe file and load and use it as a phantonJs driver, and about that you will find a tons of examples in web.

Comment: I downloaded TripleJS, its just a .exe file. And I tried to give as phantonJs Driver in C# code. It doesn't accept it. It still looking for phantomJs.exe when I run my code. I couldn't figure out how I can use TripleJS as phantonJs driver. Can you share an example with me? Btw, I am trying to implement tripleJS as a selenium webdriver in C#.