# How can I hide browser of Selenium IEDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium

[image]

I used Selenium IEDriver as the picture showed above on nuget.

I know someone will ask me why use Selenium IEDriver.I have no choice that the website can only runs correctly in Internet Explorer for it is an old website.

When the Selenium IEDriver runs,it will open a new Internet Explorer and runs on it.I just want it runs in background but not show a window.

How can I do it?Thank you.

PS:Someone said my question is duplicate and let me use trifle.js .I searched and found that Selenium WebDriver can hide browser but I just don't know how IEDriver hide browser.I want to use Selenium but not trifle.js at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set capability for IE browser to run in Headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645307/how-to-set-capability-for-ie-browser-to-run-in-headless-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other browsers will have headless option, but IE doesn't have!The hiding of browser is called headless mode, you can't do that with IE!

Comment: OK,it seems using a headless browser with IE is not easy for now IE is being more and more useless.