# How do I make Internet Explorer driver invisible using Selenium and VB?

Tags: vba, vb.net, selenium, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am using Selenium WebDriver to make some automations, using chrome I can use the `headless` argument to hide it, but I don't know the argument to hide the Internet Explorer.

```
Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
driver.AddArgument ("headless")
```

```
Dim driver As New IEDriver
driver.AddArgument ("?????????????????????")
```

[Library used - A Selenium based browser automation framework for VB.Net, VBA and VBScript](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my searching results, it looks like Internet Explorer does not support **Headless** mode.

As a work around, you can use trifleJS.

It can emulate some IE versions in a headless mode.

References:

(1) [How to Set capability for IE browser to run in Headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645307/how-to-set-capability-for-ie-browser-to-run-in-headless-mode)

(2) [TrifleJS](http://triflejs.org/)

Comment: How do I use triffle js? I downloaded the exe file from second link. How do i set capabilities and start driver