# Selenium - IE not running headless

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

Using python and selenium, I have a function for IE to run headless, but for some reason it's not working.  It works perfect for Chrome, but not IE.  I could've sworn it worked previously. Any ideas?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options as IEOptions

def openie():
    setglobalvariables()
    window_size = '1920,1080'
    ie_options = IEOptions()
    ie_options.add_argument('--headless')
    ie_options.add_argument('--window-size=%s' % window_size)
    ie_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Ie(input_path + 'IEDriverServer.exe', options=ie_options)

    url = settingsfile('url').strip()
    statusmessage(url)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    return driver
```

Comment: Are you sure you ran IE as headless using Selenium? Doesn't sound like that is an option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774761/how-do-i-make-internet-explorer-driver-invisible-using-selenium-and-vb

Comment: @RyanWilson - Apparently, I was mistaken :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, IE does not support Headless Browsing.

You can refer to this thread for verification and a workaround on how it can work:

> The IE driver does not support execution without an active, logged-in
> desktop session running. You'll need to take this up with the author
> of the solution you're using to achieve "headless" (scare quotes
> intentional) execution of IE.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4551#issuecomment-324319508

https://community.lambdatest.com/t/how-can-i-run-my-selenium-tests-in-headless-ie/5447

---

EDIT:

The second thread is of the [LambdaTest community](https://community.lambdatest.com/) and answered by me.

Comment: Thanks for the information - I guess I was wrong about it work.  I'll check out the alternative solution

Comment: Sure. If you come around with any good solutions, please post them here as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be preferable if you mentioned that you are the author of the answer in the linked forum.