# Selenium tests open IE in background on TFS build server

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, tfs

we are trying to use Selenium for testing our MVC application. On localhost in VS2017 , it´s running correct, the tests open IE, run the test and then close the IE.

On TFS build server, the tests start IE somehow on background (in Task manager I see two iexplorer.exe processes), but the window of IE is not visible. The tests find elements, but they are not able to write text in textbox, always get error like "Element cannot be interacted with via the keyboard because it is not focusable"

Localy I run Win10 and IE11, TFS build server run Windows Server 2012 R2 and IE11 .

```cs
//initialize driver in test constructor
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();      
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;   
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();


//test itself
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(appURL);
var x = driver.FindElement(By.Id("FiltrADuvodDotazu_DuvodDotazu"));
x.SendKeys("Automatizovaný test"); //here I get error
```

Is there way to run IE visibly, so the tests can interact with it?

Comment: You need to run your browser in headless mode which IE doesn't support - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645307/how-to-set-capability-for-ie-browser-to-run-in-headless-mode

Comment: But then what is different between testing localy and on TFS build server? Localy everything run correct

Comment: Locally you have a UI, in TFS there is no UI to interact with.

Comment: The build server also have a UI, so why on local it run UI and on build server the UI doesnt start? Thats what I dont understand

Comment: Unless the build agent account is logged in, there is no UI/desktop available. So your options are create a UI by logging in as the build agent account or use headless. Some might consider leaving a server environment logged in a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your agent run as a service and this is the reason the tests run on "headless mode" (and IE not supports it, like mentioned in the comments).

To solve it you need to configure the agent as an interactive process with auto-logon enabled.

When configuring the agent, select 'No' when prompted to run as a service. subsequent steps then allow you to configure the agent with auto-logon.

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations).