# Similar to chrome headless state, is there a way to access IE 11 in background?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, headless-browser

Similar to how we can browse to a webpage in chrome headless is there a way to do the same in IE 11?

The intranet site would only work on IE so can't switch to other browser.

I'm using c# so if there is any nuget that can be leveraged or any other way to do it?

The only closest solution I could find on the internet is keeping the IE minimize

Answer (score 0):

For internet explorer, I don't think we can run headless automation.

Although you can have a look at https://triflejs.org/ . This simulate IE headless behaviour.

Another thing you can do is, create a window script to invoke the test case via command line and run that script as a service.
Now when you run that as a service, all the process getting triggered from that will be running in background so you won't see browser coming up.

Answer (score 0):

The IE browser does not support the Headless mode. So it is not possible to automate the IE browser with the Headless mode.

I found that some [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645307/how-to-set-capability-for-ie-browser-to-run-in-headless-mode) said that trifle.js can help to automate the IE in Headless mode. But I am not sure whether that solution can work with the latest version of the IE browser and it can possible that you will not be able to use Selenium with it.

So you can have a check whether it can fulfil your requirements. If not, then I suggest continue with the selenium and automate the IE in minimized mode.