# Not able to ignore ssl certificate using capability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, jmeter, ssl-certificate, jsr223

Trying to run below code by disbaling ssl ccertificate using capability (capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true) via IE.

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
    
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup()
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true); 
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities)
    def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    driver.get('https://google.com/');
    WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@name='q']")));
    WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

ended up getting below error.

```
2020-10-11 09:43:21,585 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script iecONFIG, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CapabilityType for class: Script63
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CapabilityType for class: Script63
```

Does anyone know how to handle SSL certificated? and run IE with headless mode?

Comment: 1. `CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS` doesn't work for IE. We can't ignore ssl certificate using this capability. As a workaround, we can click link "Continue to this website (not recommended)." to bypass it: `driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");`. 2. IE doesn't support headless mode so we can't run it with headless mode. You can also refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645307/how-to-set-capability-for-ie-browser-to-run-in-headless-mode).

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see where do you declare the [import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) for the [CapabilityType](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.html) class, you either need to add the next line:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType
```

to the beginning of your script

or replace

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
```

with

```
capabilities.setCapability(org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
```

and I don't think you will be able to run Internet Explorer in headless mode, the only option would be running JMeter as the system service so the browser won't show up on your desktop, see [Headless Execution of Selenium Tests in Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins) article for more information if needed